# Update Field in All Subscribers DataView on Email Send

Tags: dataextensions, subscriber

When we send emails to new leads that are stored inside a Data Extension, a record is created in All Subscribers with their EmailAddress and SubscriberKey.  Our Data Extension contains extra fields like name, address, and a unique field.  Those fields are also in the All Subscribers list, how do I get those fields to populate when we send an email?

I've added a new field called "BU_Code" which is going to be used to identify which subscriber is part of which Business Unit.  This field is in the All Subscribers dataview as I added it through the admin settings.

The "BU_Code" field is also stored inside the Data Extension being used in the email send.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via simple Automation with several steps inside:

1. [Data Extract Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_extension_extract.htm&type=5) (with enabled feature to extract Data Extension, if not then open a ticket with SF Support) - that will move the Data Extension to the Safehouse;
2. [File Transfer Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_move_a_file_with_the_file_transfer_activity.htm&type=5) - that will place the file with records from the Data Extension on the SFTP (also requires SFTP access in advance)
3. [Import Activity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_update_a_list_or_data_extension_using_an_external_file.htm&type=5) - that will import back the file from SFTP to the SFMC and where you would select to import to the All Suscrbierbs list. Of course, you would need to make sure that field mapping is correct and you are not exceeding any [limits](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_use_an_import_activity.htm&type=5) anywhere.

Automation's schedule - you can set it to run daily or even hourly, so your Master Data Extension would always be aligned with the All Subscribers list.